# org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate extractOutputParameters taking too much time

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am resolving one of the Production issue, where while calling a procedure through JdbcTemplate using class org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate and method extractOutputParameters, with the same input and same number of output, sometimes this method execute very fast and sometimes it takes too much time.

I can not paste the code here as it is restricted. Can anybody give me any hint that what could be the cause of this abrupt behaviour of this method extractOutputParameters.

I have analysed memory and CPU usage, but nothing get anything there.

Comment: which jdbc driver do you use and which version?

Comment: I am using ojdbc8 driver